Unable to renaming page name in Neoload while recording
I have recorded a script in neoload, By default the neoload names the page name after the first request name. There are same requests in other transaction too. So this creates confusion while analyzing the results since all the request names are the same. We need to have unique page name to differentiate the requests.
I tried creating unique page names by modifying the naming template in Edit-> Preferences -> Project settings. I tried using the template $param.pagecount$ where page count is the variable created.
Also tried naming the pages while recording using transaction name. None of these are working.
Can anyone with experience please help in naming the page name after transaction name and request name. Also explain using this template $param.<name>$
Reference doc: https://setgetweb.com/p/neoload/698.htm
